# Release code should not work in development mode, React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

HI I want to run some code only when It is a production build like `sentry` or `google analystics` .

I have checked [Is there a way to keep debug code out of a release build in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340673/is-there-a-way-to-keep-debug-code-out-of-a-release-build-in-react-native)  this post but

```
if(__DEV__) {
    this.setState({username: 'Niel', password: 'Test'});
}
```

`__DEV__` gives me undefined variable name.

Is not working.

can someone help me out of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7814

```
Removing .babelrc seems to fix the problem.

My .babelrc:

{ "presets": ["react-native"] }
```

Comment: I don;t have such file, but i have babel.config.js file DO i make changes in that ?

Comment: What do you have in your `babel.config.js`?

Comment: @cakePHP make changes in it and try

Comment: @Konstantin, it has 
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};

Comment: Do you have `metro-react-native-babel-preset` in your devDependencies?